# Updating column value from another column when ids are matching from list in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, django-queryset

Collection data:

```
id |  item  | priority1 | priority2
----------------------------------
10 |  book  |    low    |    high    
20 |  copy  |   medium  |    low
30 | eraser |   medium  |    low  
40 |  pen   |    high   |    low
```

The list of ids provided:

```
id_list = [20, 30, 40]
```

According to the ids present in the **id_list**, I want to update the Mongodb collection for column **priority2** with same values from column **priority1**.
So the result collection data will be:

```
id |  item  | priority1 | priority2
----------------------------------
10 |  book  |    low    |    high    
20 |  copy  |   medium  |   medium
30 | eraser |   medium  |   medium
40 |  pen   |    high   |    high
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an update with aggregation pipeline for this:

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: {
    $in: [
      20,
      30,
      40
    ]
  }
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "priority2": "$priority1"
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

See this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MyDGixjZjOi).

Comment: Can you please write it for mongoengine queryset?

Comment: Sorry, I've never used mongoengine. Hope the query sets you on the right path.